# Deploying iOS app using enterprise account

Tags: ios, xcode

I've read the tutorials regarding this, it says I need a .ipa and .plist file. And by archiving the project the xcode automatically creates these. But for some reason the xcode doesnt give the .plist file. So i needed to create .plist file using the template given.

But what should I do next? I want to upload my app in web server so that by clicking the download link it will be automatically installed. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found what must be done! What I tried is save the .ipa file to dropbox(or where ever server you want), then created the .plist file and filling up the url using the directory of the .ipa file(which was uploaded to dropbox, for this case it is the link when you clicked share this). Upload the .plist to dropbox also. Then I created a .html file where there's a link (pertaining to the download link of .plist). Lastly upload the .html to dropbox. Thats it!